# What is French for "(Immigration) Emergency Brake"? (It's a political term)

Tags: politique

This is a Brexit term and I want to read French sources and opinion on the subject that it identifies.

Comment: @ Laurent S  It seems that what is needed is nothing more than the French equivalent, so as to be able to do research in French papers and othe sources written in French.

Comment: @user168676: correct.   I went missing from this site after answering own question (one cannot accept own answer immediately).  I have now accepted own answer so as to take this off the unanswered queue.

Comment: This is a mere word for word translation with no explanation whatsoever; the concept predates the Brexit and was technically nothing more than an "[alert and safeguard mechanism](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/media/21787/0216-euco-conclusions.pdf)" to control the impact of the inflow of immigrant workers on social services. This was not about security. See the Wikipedia article: "Des limitations sont introduites aux indemnités dont peuvent bénéficier les immigrés européens au Royaume-Uni mais uniquement les nouveaux immigrés et avec l'autorisation du Conseil européen."(Wikipedia)

Comment: See [source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rendum_sur_l%27appartenance_du_Royaume-Uni_%C3%A0_l%27Union_europ%C3%A9enne#N%C3%A9gociations_avec_l'Union_europ%C3%A9enne).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"frein d'urgence" as used in this article, [nouvelobs.com](https://www.nouvelobs.com/monde/20160128.REU4623/l-ue-propose-un-frein-d-urgence-a-londres-sur-l-immigration.html)

Answer (score 1):

looks like the handbrake. "frein à main".
to suggest a strong opposition we often use figuratively: "X à provoqué une levée de bouclier"

Comment: _Une levée de boucliers_ is indeed more idiomatic than _frein d'urgence_ or _frein à main_ which convey the meaning but is not so clear